# Center html ul completely in container

Tags: html, css

I have this unordered list and I want to display it vertically and also make it completely centered inside the parent container. I've managed to make it display vertically and be centered on the x-axis, but not on the y-axis. "vertical-alignment: middle;" doesn't seem to do what I want.

Consider this html-code:

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you mean horizontally when you say vertically. Also, `width: 100;` is invalid. Needs a unit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically center ul in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078868/vertically-center-ul-in-div) and a multitude of same questions found by searching SO.

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To vertically align on y-axis add the below given css to ul:

```
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
```

And remove `width:100;` from ul tag.

**Demo**

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;   /*add this */
  justify-content:center; /*add this */
  align-items:center; /*add this */
  
  text-align: center
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` for the div and `margin: auto` for the ul. And remove `height` and `width` rules from ul. here's the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bswranpq/)

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

div {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

ul {
    margin: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Post your code in your question, not jsFiddle please

Answer (score 0):

To align vertically u can use `line-height`.
use line-height instead of height in div tag.

```
div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  line-height: 200px;  /*change this */
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  line-height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd say its a bad practice of using line-height. Because we might need to override line-height of the paragraph/content comes under that parent div.