# Centering box into middle of page using CSS

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm just starting out making simple webpages using HTML and CSS and I wanted to center my content in the middle of the page. With my code, I have the content centered from the left and the right, but I wanted to also center it from top and bottom. If you were to test my code, you would see that there is no spacing at the top. How would I fix this to have center from not only left and right but from top and bottom?

My CSS code looks something like this:

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: green;
}

#homePage {
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

My html code looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="homePage">
        <header> Logo and Twitter </header> 
        <ul id="pageNav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="purchase.html">Purchase</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
        </ul>               
        <footer> Content for footer goes here </footer>
    </div>                                  
</body>
```

Comment: Check it on [HERE](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-div

check the above link you can find your answer there

Answer (score 2):

Google "dead centre css". Mind the spelling. You'll get [this invaluable link](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use positioning like this:

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}
#homePage {
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3MF8c/)**

By using absolute positioning on `#homePage`, setting the top, right, bottom, and left to zero, and the margin to auto, it will center horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to change the display?
For example:

```css
#homePage {
  width: 960px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vertical middle align is not easy as horizontal align using width and margin. For me the best solution is

[How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

it doesn't include any hack and fits with responsive design

Answer (score 0):

Great CSS trick by j08691! You can also try this on page load and re-size:

```
var _nBodyHeight = $('body').height();
var _nTop = (_nBodyHeight/2) - ($('#homePage').height()/2);
$('#homePage').css('top', _nTop);
```