# CSS - Circle won't fit in center of another

Tags: css

I can't make one circle center inside another.

I can't understand whats wrong.
I have also tried doing it with a square, and that wont work too.

Heres my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2a8or58/5/).

```
.circle {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    border-radius: 85px 85px 85px 85px;
    background: lime;
}
.circle-inner {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
border-radius: 75px 75px 75px 75px;          
background: red;
```

Comment: In addition to the comments below - here's an alternative, http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/x7dz0sxm/ . Create a larger circle, add some padding, and have the child circle fill the remaining space. If you want a smaller circle, just up the padding on the parent and the child would adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give same size to both containers and add a padding to the wrapper like    `padding:10px;`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e2a8or58/8/)**. It is the most simple way i think of.

```
.circle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius: 85px 85px 85px 85px;
    background: lime;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D yep, this is an easy way too, unblured box shadow would do too :).there's many ways :) , as display:flex and margin:auto; too http://jsfiddle.net/e2a8or58/12/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code for your inner circle:

```
position:relative;
top:10px;
```

Note that you can also make your code a lot cleaner by using shorthand:

Change `border-radius: 75px 75px 75px 75px;` into `border-radius: 75px;`
The same goes for .circle

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why margin dosen't work verticaly?

Comment: In .circle and .circle-inner you have not used margin vertically. Take a look this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: You cannot use `margin-top:auto` and `margin-bottom:auto` to centre a div vertically because these values are defaulted at zero, even if your div has a height. Check this out for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-div

Comment: @ctwheels , margin:auto; works in the flex model configuration : http://jsfiddle.net/e2a8or58/12/ (if browser understands : display:flex;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this:
Make your circles same size and add padding to containing circle

```
/*My css*/

            .circle {
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: lime;
                padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: 20px is twice too much ;)

Comment: Oh, my bad, haha. I didn't see your answer! kms
Also, you're right - just an example of how it works~

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using:

```
.circle-inner {
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/x683mtbh/