# Why doesn't margin: auto 0px; vertically center a block as margin: 0px auto; horizontally centers it?

Tags: html, css

You can easy set width to auto with `margin:0px, auto`

```css
#container{
  background-color: blue;
  height:600px;
  width:600px;
  margin:0px auto; }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

But why can't you set height to auto with `margin:auto 0px`? I mean, Why doesn't `margin: auto 0px;` vertically center a block as `margin: 0px auto;` horizontally centers it?

```css
#container{
  background-color: blue;
  height:600px;
  width:600px;
  margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but your css is incorrect in your second snippet.  You have a comma between `0px` and `auto`

Comment: The question seems to be, "*Why doesn't `margin: auto 0px;` vertically center a block as `margin: 0px auto;` horizontally centers it?*" For that, "[Using margin:auto to vertically align div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-div)" provides an explanation.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks, that's what I mean. I have updated the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to accomplish a centered vertical-align depends on what exactly you'd like to do.

With block level elements, each div/box/etc is stacked left to right and then top to bottom. A good explanation of block elements [can be found here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) and another one [here on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). Here is an [in-depth look at the display property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).

- You can use translateY and percentages as described [in this blog post](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)
- If for some reason you wish to place your div in the center of the screen for good, [Here is a very good technique to vertically center with an in-depth explanation.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

Comment: There are better resources than w3schools - [Block elements (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) / [Inline elements (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) / [The display property (CSS Tricks)](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/). [Here is a very good technique to vertically center with an in-depth explanation.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

Comment: Thanks for adding that! I was blocked from leaving more links because I haven't left very many answers.

Comment: Oh, didn't think about that. I have added them all to your answer; I think you should be able to edit the wording now, if you want, and still keep the links active. :)

Comment: Also, it would be even better if you could add a small snippet of HTML / CSS for each of those techniques that are linked. When you answer a question, think: "if these links go dead, is my answer still helpful?"

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have a syntax error. It should be:

`margin: 0 auto;`

Take out the 'px' and remove the comma.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` and `margin: 0px auto;` do exactly the same thing.