# Banner shrink on scroll, text stays middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my banner to shrink on scroll.
How can I get the text to start in the middle of the banner, and ends at the middle when shrinking? Right now the text fall down on scroll instead of going up.

Heres what I have so far:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>175){
        // animate fixed div to small size:
        $('.wrapper').stop().animate({ height: 57 , 'padding-top': 20},100);
    } else {
        //  animate fixed div to original size
        $('.wrapper').stop().animate({ height: 115, 'padding-top': 0},100);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnsUB/255/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind, you can do a little hack,

You can add `display:table` in `.wrapper` and `display:table-cell` in `.text`.
Then you can give `vertical-align:middle` for `.text`. Using this method, you don't need to worry about position of `.text`. Any padding can be given directly in `.wrapper`.

http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/a0ww0dhg/

ref: [Using margin:auto to vertically-align a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-div)

Comment: you can try `text-align: center` on `.text`, make sure there is no left or right padding for .wrapper (else it will add an offset,) [if u dont mind, a vote up will help.. :)]

Comment: I don't have 15 reputations to vote up yet, but I'll be sure to vote up once I do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `<p>` margin in jquery like this:

```
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>175){
        // animate fixed div to small size:
        $('.wrapper').stop().animate({ height: 57 , 'padding-top': 0},100);
        $('.wrapper p').css('margin-top', 22);
    } else {
        //  animate fixed div to original size
        $('.wrapper').stop().animate({ height: 300, 'padding-top': 0},100);
        $('.wrapper p').css('margin-top', 130);
    }
});
```

You can use method chaining too:

```
        $('.wrapper').stop()
            .animate({ height: 300, 'padding-top': 0},100)
            .find('p')
            .css('margin-top', 130);
```