# How can I vertically align the contents of a cell in a Vaadin Grid?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have the following code that successfully centers the contents of a cell in my Vaadin grid.

```
        this.grid.setRowHeight(65);
        this.grid.setStyleGenerator(item -> "v-align-center");
```

It makes it looks like this.

How can I also vertically center?  When I tried adding the style name v-align-middle it did nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I played with CSS styles and default `TextRenderer` but did not get it working. When you switch to `HtmlRenderer` then you have more styling options with additional `div` HTML elements. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-a-div) for styling hints. For example, this should work when you can use flex layouting:

```
<div style="display:flex; height:100%; width:100%">
    <div style="margin: auto;">11 m³</div>
</div>
```

Another workaround is to use a `ComponentRenderer` column with a `HorizontalLayout` set to 100% height and its child component aligned to middle center.

Answer (score 2):

If you're setting a specific height on the rows then it's pretty straight forward to achieve with CSS.

Rather than using the StyleGenerator, I'd just apply a CSS Class to the Grid itself.

**Java:**

```
addStyleName("my-custom-grid");
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-custom-grid .v-grid-body .v-grid-row .v-grid-cell {
    height: 65px;
    line-height: 65px;
}
```