# Center div in Kendo for Angular Dialog

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

[In this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrzttx) I have a Kendo for Angular Dialog that contains a div. I need to center the dive vertically/horizontally in the Dialog area. How is this possible? I tried with `"margin: auto"` but did not work.

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <kendo-dialog [width]="340" [height]="200">
          <kendo-dialog-titlebar>
             The Title
        </kendo-dialog-titlebar>
         <div id="div1">CENTER THE DIV</div>
      </kendo-dialog>
    `,
    styles: [`
      #div1{
        width:120px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: yellow;
      }

      `]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public opened: boolean = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this thread reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26079837/7009923), and adapted to the context of the Dialog content:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [`
  #div1{
    margin: auto auto;
    width:100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .k-content.k-dialog-content {
    display: flex;
  }
  `]
```

[Modified example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrzttx-ejq7e1?file=app/app.component.ts)