# Div not being centered when using margin: auto; (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a working example website from the bootstrap template website and was analysing the code to understand how they created it.  Namely how they centered the text on the first page located [here](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/). The code for that snipplet is,

```
<header class="masthead text-center text-white d-flex"> <!-- Background image set here -->
    <div class="container m-auto">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto">
                   ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                   ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

So then I noticed that the m-auto was doing the centering. However, when I attempt to create it from scratch for myself and create this basic code,

```
 <style>
    #frontpage {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
  </style>

<section id="frontpage">
  <div class="container m-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
        <h1> YOU CAN DO IT </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <h1> I should be centered </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

It doesn't center at all.
What am I forgetting here?

I would suspect that the container gets centered inside it's parent, which takes up the page.

Comment: remove cache and try again, also it will align horizontally, making it align vertically is little more difficult try searching here

Comment: There is no link attached to your "here"

Comment: Removing cache did nothing btw. (i.e ctrl + F5)

Answer (score 0):

you have copied the code but styles not included for them if guess correctly. anyway, I have corrected please try this one.

```
 <style>
        #frontpage {
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100%;
        }

.center-me{
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
}
      </style>

    <section id="frontpage">
            <div class="center-me">
                    <div >
                      <h1> YOU CAN DO IT </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                      <h1> I should be centered </h1>
                    </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: But this does not use the bootstrap framework, which I was trying to stick towards.

Comment: Plus its not vertically centered

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-a-div  This post says that any flex should be centered using margin: auto; Which makes it think that the d-flex in the original working one made it work, however it didn't when added to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?
**Version 1**

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/YdEWZJ

**HTML**

```
<section id="frontpage">
  <div class="container m-auto">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
        <h1> YOU CAN DO IT </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <h1> I should be centered </h1>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#frontpage{
  background-color:pink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.col-8{
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin-left:auto !important;
  margin-right:auto !important;
  text-align:center;
}
```

**Version 2**
This also centers the text vertically
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/KbygzX

**HTML**

```
<section id="frontpage">
  <div class="container m-auto">
    <div class="row vert-align">
          <div class="col-8">
        <h1>YOU CAN DO IT</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <h1> I should be centered </h1>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#frontpage{
  background-color:pink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.col-8{
  margin-left:auto !important;
  margin-right:auto !important;
  text-align:center;
}

.row.vert-align{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: No, the container should be vertically and horizontally centered.

Comment: I've added a second suggestion @J.Doe

Comment: Seems to do the trick. The easiest solution I could find was making the frontpage a d-flex, and then margin: auto; for the container. That centered it well and was easily understood.