# Why does mx-auto work but my-auto doesn't?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I create a 20px*20px  element inside a 200px*200px  element, mx-auto centers the 20*20  but my-auto does not.

```
<div class="border" style="width: 200px; height:200px">
   <div class="mx-auto my-auto border" style="width:20px; height:20px"></div>
</div>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Please see the answer from the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12417336/7653007)

Comment: add `d-flex` to border and it will work