# Div within div vertical center with position relative?

Tags: css

I thought it was possible to center a div vertically within another div with its position set to relative? I'm not a fan of position absolute, as it layers it on top of everything.

What am i missing here? It can be centeret horizontal no problem.

```css
.main_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.main_container .inner_container {
  position relative;
  height: 90%;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="inner_container">
    //Some content here, img and text etc.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide corresponding HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) instead of relative positioning:

```css
.main_container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main_container .inner_container {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="inner_container">
    //Some content here, img and text etc.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah yes ofcourse - thank you. 
I find it odd, that i'm not able to center using Margin in a relative position though?

Comment: Prior to flexbox, vertical centering in CSS was painful. Using `auto` for vertical margins would compute as `0` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12417336/124386) for more details.

Comment: it would be good to help us close this million-th duplicate. I am pretty sure you know a lot of centering question around.